# Who is not in the garden?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Billy the gardener uses a grey lego bolt to plant beans inside the timber ring, Sallah!

Who is not in the garden?

Hint:

> A fellowship of nine

Comment: What the ... ? :-) I predict this will start off with several DVs and maybe even VTCs, and then suddenly get loads of UVs once it's solved or people realise it's a genuine puzzle. (Edit: just to be clear, I haven't voted on it at all yet.)

Comment: It is enigmatic, and should be really tough to understand. But if you in any way should be so clever (or lucky) to get on the right track, it should be plenty of confirmation along the way.

Comment: Sam is part of the fellowship (of 9) of the ring, and he is a gardener. his pony is named Bill. that's all I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based mostly on the answer by Otaia (I changed some of the clues and arrived at a different answer.. Then based on more hints I changed more clues and arrived at his original answer... )

> **Aragorn** is not in the garden.
>  The sentence refers to The Lord of the Rings.
>
>  **Billy** - Pippin, played by Billy Boyd
>  **the gardener** - Samwise
>  **Grey** - Gandalf the Grey
>  **Lego** - Legolas
>  **Bolt** - Merry, portrayed by Dominic Monaghan, who also played the Bolt in X-Men Origins (Credit user3453281)
>  **Beans** - Boromir, portrayed by Sean Bean
>  **Timber** - Frodo, played by Elijah **Wood***
>  **Sallah** - played by John Rhys-Davies, who also played Gimli
>
>  * Though on an interesting note I found that many believe that the 'orn' at the end of Aragorn's name means 'tree'.) Which could make Timber refer to Aragorn and make Frodo the answer. I however think that is more of a stretch than timber referring to Frodo.

Comment: You got it, congratulations!

Answer (score 9):

> **Aragorn** is not in the garden.
>  Many parts of the sentence refer to members of the Fellowship of the Ring.
>
>  **Billy the gardener** - Samwise
>  **Grey** - Gandalf the Grey
>  **Lego** - Legolas
>  **Beans** - Boromir, portrayed by Sean Bean
>  **Timber** - Merry and Pippin befriend Treebeard
>  **Ring** - Frodo, the ring-bearer
>  **Sallah** - played by John Rhys-Davies, who also played Gimli

Comment: You are on the right track...:-)

Comment: I would say that Billy could refer to Pippin (Played by Billy Boyd)

Comment: Also timber might refer to Aragorn since many believe the 'orn' at the end of his name means 'tree'... If those two things were true then it would be Merry who is not in the Garden

Comment: The ring is not referring to Frodo, but just a clue for the complete riddle...