# Mission: Impossible 3

Tags: word, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

Yesterday Ethan Hunt received the following message:

> Take Qantas flight number 47, leaving 11 o'clock on the 5th of April. At your destination airport use any bus with number 2, 8, 18 (or bus 18/1). You can take with you 107.8 kilograms of luggage.

What is the goal of Ethan's journey?

Comment: @AE I'd put it in the same category as enigmatic puzzles like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/a-dj-at-a-radio-station) and [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9098/who-is-not-in-the-garden). Arguably it's a cryptogram, but one could also argue it's more like a riddle since all the clues point to the same answer. Never mind - the current tagging is a good compromise :-)

Comment: @randal'thor fair enough :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy, easy.  The goal of Ethan Hunt's journey must be

> Argentina

Explanation:

> * The country Argentina is called after silver (= argentum in Latin).
>  * Silver has the chemical element number 47, the flight number of Ethan.
>  * The element silver is in group 11, period 5 (11 o'clock on April 5th)
>  * The electron configuration of silver is 2, 8, 18, 18, 1 per shell (bus with number 2, 8, 18 or 18/1).
>  * The relative atomic mass of silver is 107.8682 (107.8 kilograms of luggage)

See also

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver

Comment: I'm impressed you cottoned on to this so quickly! What about "Qantas" - is that a clue pointing to the same answer?

Comment: @randal'thor: "Top silver-producing mines are Cannington (Australia)..." which is in Queensland. Maybe this is the connection. From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver#Occurrence_and_extraction